# Ubuntu development: Sass, Coffeescript, Nose

Tags: python, ubuntu, sass, nose, coffeescript

in my current Django project I have Sass, Coffeescript and Nose. Now all of these have watch options but I would like to automate this so I don't have to turn them all one by one each time I start working.

What's a recommend approach for doing this? It's a Django project so something Pythony would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Python/Django guy, myself, but some searching finds these potentially useful plugins:

- https://github.com/ashchristopher/django-sass (Django plugin for Sass)
- https://github.com/dsc/coffeecup (WSGI middleware for CoffeeScript)

Comment: I guess that this might be a better approach.